# A symmetric matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could anybody tell me how to do this question:
If A is a symmetric matrix, show that there exists a nonsingular matrix P such that

```
    P^T * A * P = [I_sub_r 0 0; 0 -I_sub_u 0; 0 0 0]
```

(P^T indicates transpose, semicolon indicates "enter," as in Matlab)

Comment: This cannot be true in general, the matrix on the right is singular, and if $A$ is non singular, then so is $P^T A P$.

Comment: I believe what the OP means is that if the matrix $A$ is non-singular, then the zero matrix will have dimension $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A symmetric matrix is diagonalizable by the Spectral Decomposition Theorem. Hence there exists orthogonal $Q$ such that $A=QDQ'$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

In fact, $D$ has the eigenvalues of $A$ as its entries and $Q$ contains the orthonormal eigenvectors.

Hence you have to find your $Q$ by first finding the eigenvalues of $A$, then the eigenvectors and then turning the eigenvectors into an orthonormal basis. Now some of these eigenvalues are positive, some negative, some may be $0$.

Hence you have, after possible reordering of your eigenvalues and hence eigenvectors, that $Q'AQ=diag(\lambda_1^2,\lambda_2^2,...,\lambda_r^2,-\mu_1^2,-\mu_2^2,...,-\mu_u^2,0,...,0)$. This is just a way of writing the positive and negative eigenvalues. Notice that we can do this since eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real.

Now, let $v_i$ be the eigenvector for $\lambda_i^2$ and $t_i$ be the eigenvector for $-\mu_i^2$ in $Q$. Let us define a new matrix $Q$ from $P$ such that $Q=(a_1|...|a_r|b_1|...|b_u|c_1|...|c_{n-r-u})$ where $a_i=\dfrac{v_i}{\lambda_i}$,$b_i=\dfrac{t_i}{\mu_i}$ and $c_i$ are the eigenvectors for $0$.

Notice that $Q$ is non-singular. This $Q$ works.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you understood everything. It will be better if you actually verify all the things said here, on paper.